# Settings page to show only once

Tags: ios, objective-c

I have an app which should only show the settings page once: when the app is opened for the first time.

Now this works, and when the user presses the middle button on the iPhone it then reopens the app and carries on from the main screen - that's great. But if I double click on the iPhone button and swipe the application off, it will then go to the settings screen again and not to where it was.

Why is it doing that? How can I make my app only show its settings once?

```
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions

    NSUserDefaults *settingsscreen = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];
    [settingsscreen registerDefaults:[NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:[NSNumber numberWithBool:YES],@"firstTime", nil]];
    BOOL firstTime = [settingsscreen boolForKey:@"firstTime"];

    if ( firstTime==YES) {
        [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] setBool:YES forKey:@"SettingsShown"];
        [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] synchronize];
        self.window.rootViewController = [self.window.rootViewController.storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"SetUpNav"];
    }
    else
    {
        return YES;
    }
}
```

Comment: Are You setting the variable to Yes once the setting screen is dismissed ,If not please do that

Answer (score 4):

Don't use `if ( firstTime==YES) {` based on `@"firstTime"`, because that flag is never actually saved. You should be using the flag saved with the `@"SettingsShown"` key.

```
BOOL firstTime = [settingsscreen boolForKey:@"SettingsShown"];

if (!firstTime) {
    ...
```

Comment: works fine either way, but when you swipe the app off when you double click on the button on the iPhone and swipe it off then it still goes to the settings page.

Comment: So you have removed `@"firstTime"` from the code, and you're checking `@"SettingsShown"` and saving it inside the `if`? And it still isn't working? You should update the question with your new code...

Answer (score 1):

Instead doing in appDelegate try to acheive it in setting Page itself

```
     -(void) viewDidLoad {

       NSUserDefaults *defaults = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];

       username = [defaults objectForKey:@"username"];

      if (username != NULL ) {
            [self selfLogin];
         }
}

-(void)selfLogin{

        nextPageController = [[NextPageViewController alloc]init];
        [self.navigationController pushViewController:nextPageController                animated:YES];

}
```

Comment: There is no real difference here other than you use more memory and have a view controller presented that might not need to be - the user defaults usage check is the same (and ambiguous as to what sets and saves for key `username`)